# MySql database for lot of data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, nosql

I want to create an mobile app that need to send data every minute to backend server with mysql database.

So if I have 10 000 users that work 8 hours a day that will be:

60 request * 8 hours * 30 days * 12 months = 172800 reuqest per year for one user.

10 000 users * 172800 = 1 728 000 000

and this is I think a lot of data for mysql database, so what you suggest? What I need to use? Which kind of database? NoSql or mysql can handle this ?

Comment: I think is a lot of requests for a mobile app!

Comment: What kind of data are you going to store ?

Comment: but I need to send only lat,longitde data, and currenct time...

Comment: I need to store coordinates and time

Comment: App need to track user and every minute to send their location ...

Comment: Would the user be aware of the bandwidth per year the app will take?

Comment: it's still only 54 queries per second, and only during those 8 hours anyways.

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question without knowing how your application will query this database, and how the data will be used and archived.

Comment: This will drain mobile battery and app will be a flaw

Comment: Have you looked at local storage?

Comment: ok, maybe localStorage can be answer ... and I can make sync every half an hour?

Comment: This will drain mobile battery and app will be a flaw, but the app will work on backend, etc. like FitBit and every other app that track user activity ...

Comment: @LaraBeginer thats possible but you would have to try it and then if you can't get it to work then it would be a new question.

Comment: @LaraBeginer When you say mobile app, you've tagged PHP, is this going to be a browser based app?

Comment: the mobile app but connceted with rest api on backend (php,mysql), so I plan to build phonegap native app with rest apion backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 10,000 users data every minute, then that is 10,000/60 ~= 200 inserts per second. That is a large load, but not unreasonable.  However, it does bring up a lot of questions such as:

- How will this data be used?
- What is your backup strategy?
- How much history is needed?
- How are you managing the network bandwidth?
- What is the peak insert rate?
- How quickly does data need to be available?
- How important is ACID-compliance?

The answers to these questions should help you decide the best data source. Both MySQL and key-value No-SQL databases are up to this challenge. MySQL databases can handle billions of rows per year. Typical No-SQL databases (MongoDB, Dynamo DB, and so on) can also handle this volume of data.

Comment: 1. I only need to send user location (coordinates)

Comment: so like every app do that (fitBit, every app that track user activity etc. health apps)

Comment: @LaraBeginer Why not use some sort of datastreaming service to send the coordinates?

Comment: ? how , I dont understand how to datastreaming?

Comment: @LaraBeginer Try Googling WebSockets

Comment: @LaraBeginer That would be a different question about Mobile Dev , which needs to be specific to JAVA/ Android, iOS development Objective C, etc. The answer to the above one still stands, MySQL can / should be able to handle the requests.

Comment: but I will create app with phonegap for frontend and rest api on backend, there will not be Objective C

Comment: @TimDev Where did you get the Idea that mobile apps can't use PHP,JS and HTML?

Comment: @Stijn I never said it wasn't possible, you wan't me to list all possible languages how to create mobile apps?  Python, C#, C++,JAVA, javascript ??Etc etc?

Comment: @TimDev Let me qoute your comment: "which needs to be specific to"

Comment: I will add the word "etc"... jeez

Comment: Ok, lets make conclusion: battery problem, server problem, so I need to make locaStorage service that will make sync every hour

Comment: You don't simply take all our ideas and try to implement it all.  You need to sum up your wishes, available tools and hardware. Then make choices based on all of the above. This is what Gordon is trying to say. So MySQL can handle it, the other questions are other actionpoints you need to look at.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL can handle this, no problem. The second question you need to ask yourself if your server can handle 10K request a minute(maybe you are sharing it).

And you should try to count requests per second or minute, per year is a bit ambiguous. So saying 1 request a minute per user with 10K users is enough information.
And it's a lot, but do-able.

If you need the data I would tweak performance.

For example if you don't mind a delay of 1 hour:  Register data each minute in your phone DB,  only send the data every hour and insert in in your MySQL as a batch.
That's 1/60th of the requests and insert queries.
This is good for your server-load, and for user experience i.e. draining battery life.

Comment: I completely agree with the local storage, however what about handling the localstorage if the user logs out of the app?

Comment: I see similar app that do that with more users, etc. fitbit and similar health app track user position every seconds, steps and similar...

Comment: Mobile apps can have background services running who continue to do things you want, for example send the collected data each hour. It depends on when you want to send data, the user needs to be aware if you collect data and send it while app isn't even open. For example you can collect data when a user is logged in and stop collecting it when user logs out. And the sending part is done entirely asynchronous by your service.

Comment: Ok, lets make conclusion: battery problem, server problem, so I need to make locaStorage service that will make sync every hour

Comment: These are not conclusions, these are open questions and options.   You need to sum up your wishes, available tools and hardware. Then make choices based on all of the above. This is what Gordon is trying to say. So MySQL can handle it, the other questions are other points you need to look at, and improve your design / proof of concept.